# Conexion Nextion con Arduino

Tags: arduino, serialport

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí][image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]Tengo un problema que llevo días batallando, estoy realizando una conexion de una pantalla nextion NX8048T070 con arduino, estoy usando el Serial de mi Arduino Uno y mi idea es cambiar lo que dice una caja de texto de la pantalla, ya intente de todo y no logro nada, el texto cambia en el debug de Nextion pero no en fisico, ¿que puedo hacer? Igual ya intente con la libreria Nextion
Agregue la imagen, practicamente es como la conexion de abajo, en un momento puedo subir la foto de la conexion que tengo yo

```
void setup() {
  // put your setup code here, to run once:
  Serial.begin(9600);
}

void loop() {

  Serial.print("t0.txt=");     // This is sent to the nextion display to set what object name (before the dot) and what atribute (after the dot) are you going to change.
  Serial.print("\"");          // Since we are sending text, and not a number, we need to send double quote before and after the actual text.
  Serial.print("De entrada");  // This is the text you want to send to that object and atribute mentioned before.
  Serial.print("\"");          // Since we are sending text, and not a number, we need to send double quote before and after the actual text.
  Serial.write(0xff);          // We always have to send this three lines after each command sent to the nextion display.
  Serial.write(0xff);
  Serial.write(0xff);

  delay(1000);
  
  Serial.print("t0.txt=");     // This is sent to the nextion display to set what object name (before the dot) and what atribute (after the dot) are you going to change.
  Serial.print("\"");          // Since we are sending text, and not a number, we need to send double quote before and after the actual text.
  Serial.print("Apoco si");  // This is the text you want to send to that object and atribute mentioned before.
  Serial.print("\"");          // Since we are sending text, and not a number, we need to send double quote before and after the actual text.
  Serial.write(0xff);          // We always have to send this three lines after each command sent to the nextion display.
  Serial.write(0xff);
  Serial.write(0xff);
  delay(1000);
}
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí][image]

[[image: Al segundo, cambio a este][4]]

Comment: Es importante que pongas una foto de las conexiones. ¿Seguro que así funciona? Las librerías vienen con ejemplos, probaste alguno?

Comment: Ya probé las bibliotecas y conexiones, pensé que talvez el tx y rx estaban fallando pero el Arduino si recibe información de la pantalla

Comment: Listo, ahi estan las conexiones

Comment: También te falta la tierra común (GND) entre Arduino y el display. Tienes que tirar un cable desde GND (Arduino) hasta el cable negro en lo que parece ser el negativo de la fuente de poder del display. Revisa las polaridades.

Comment: Intentare lo del GND, tambien lei por ahi que la libreria Nextion debe modificarse con un editor de texto para Arduino Uno. Ya use SoftwareSerial pero tampoco pasa algo :c

Comment: Todos los circuitos deben compartir GND para tener un punto común desde el cual medir sus señales. Los voltajes no son absolutos, sino diferencias calculadas respecto a ese punto común, convencionalmente llamado GND.

Comment: De acuerdo, en unos momentos hare lo del GND y comento como me fue

Comment: Ya conecte la tierra común y no cambia ): Sin embargo, note que en el nextion editor al abrir el debug si hay un cambio de texto. pero sigue sin cambiar en la parte fisica